# JQuery Ajax Post with data not completing

Tags: jquery, post

I have the following but there seems to be an issue with the postdata as the alert is not displayed. How do I correctly create the postdata to include the option chosen?

HTML

```
<select id="reportTypeChosen" onchange="reportType()">
    <option value="1">Opt1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt3</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT

```
function reportType() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("reportTypeChosen");
    var choosenType = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    var postdata = "{choice: " + choosenType + "}";
    $.post("setreporttype.php", function(postdata, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
```

This gives the error in the console: data is not defined

I have also tried:

```
function reportType() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("reportTypeChosen");
    var choosenType = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    $.post("setreporttype.php", function({choice: choosenType}, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
}
```

This does not work either but without any errors.

UPDATE:
postdata was in the incorrect place. Corrected version below:

```
function reportType() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("reportTypeChosen");
    var choosenType = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    $.post("setreporttype.php", {choice: choosenType}, function(data, status){
 alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
```

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? Server logs, network tab in Dev tools, error handler for post? Hard to suggest stuff when you don't mention what you have tried

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. **Read the error message**.

Comment: All works as I debug to $.post. Values appear to correct up until that point.

Comment: You'll get a Reference error because `data` is not defined because you called it `postdata` on the previous line. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: That's assuming the success callback ever fires because `var postdata = "{choice: " + choosenType + "}";` is not encoded in any data format commonly used for HTTP requests. (It isn't multipart, it isn't URL encoded, and it isn't JSON)

Comment: @quentin. That's after they fix the current problem, the callback is not getting called? It is not JSON because properties aren't quoted (to op)

Comment: From the edit: `data is not defined` is because you haven't defined `data` - you've defined `postdata`

Comment: @JuanMendes — See my previous comment (but debugging that again should be obvious if they looked at the developer tools so so they see what the response was)

Comment: Re edit: As I said: You'll get a Reference error because data is not defined because you called it postdata on the previous line. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: You're not actually posting your data, you're providing a success callback as the 2nd arg which jquery then assumes you don't have any data to post (or that it's on the url).  Try: `$.post("setreporttype.php", postdata, function(data, status) { alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); });`  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks - spotted the problem was the postdata in the incorrect place. Thank you

Comment: Recommend closing as typo.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the post function with two params, URl and a success callback, so you're sending an empty post (please be more clear though as to your debugging though) and then looking for the data you want to send in the reply from the callback.

You probably want this:

```
$.post({my-url}, {data-to-send}, function({data-from-server}){
  doStuff(data-from-server)
});
```

Comment: Yes - I see the postdata is in the wrong place. Silly mistake. Thank you.